# How to stop a statement to work while it's false Java

Tags: java

I have created an `ArrayList` and I limited its size to 10. Now I add `String`s to it while its size ≤ 10.

How to stop function to proceed after the size is 10, and to make it wait (not to go further) after for example I delete an Item and now the size is 9, after that it sees that the size is now 9 and it can add one more element.

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public void push(String s) throws InterruptedException
{
    if(arrayList.size() < 10 )
        {
            arrayList.add(s);
        }
    else
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("FULL!");
        }
}

public String get()
{
    if(arrayList.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("This is empty");        
        }
    else
        {
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(0));
            arrayList.remove(0);
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(0));
        }
    return null;
}
```

and in Main

```
FIFO fifo = new FIFO();
fifo.push("helladadaow");
fifo.push("hellow");
fifo.push("hel2");
fifo.push("hell2w");
fifo.push("hell4w");
fifo.push("hel2w");
fifo.push("helladadaow");
fifo.push("hellow");
fifo.push("hel2");
fifo.push("hell2w");
// it stops here 
// now if I delete
fifo.get();
//it will push again
fifo.push("hell4w");
fifo.push("hel2w");
```

- `void put(String);`
  It puts the `String` parameter into the `ArrayList`. **If the `ArrayList` is full, the caller must wait.**
- `String get();`
  Returns and removes the oldest element from the `ArrayList`. **If the `ArrayList` is empty, the caller must wait.**

Comment: Define "it stops here". If `fifo.push()` literally stops (never returns), then `fifo.get()` will not be called, ever.

Comment: Don't exit your push-method if the list is full but rather try after a short time again.

Comment: void put(String). It puts the String parameter into the arrayList. If the arrayListis full, the caller 
must wait.
 String get(). Returns and removes the oldest element from the arrayList. It the arrayListis empty, 
the caller must wait.

Comment: I have edited a little bit my question, look at the end

Comment: This only makes sense in a multithreaded program where some other thread will eventually remove items from the list while you are waiting.  But then, you'll need to use proper synchronization or your code will wreak havoc.  Once you are doing this, you need no longer sleep repetitively.  Rather notify the thread that wants to insert that the list is now ready as the other thread removes items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want a bounded queue which will sleep until there is capacity free you can use the [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). Internally it will use a [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to wait for capacity. It is kind of a wait/notify.

Comment: This is probably the solution but it won't work with the OP's code where the elements are inserted and removed *by the same thread*.  No solution can possibly do what the OP requests in this case.  (Oh, except that this is probably homework and he is not allowed to use an `ArrayBlockingQueue`…)

Comment: Yes, it is a homework :D, it is not writen if we are allowed or not to use it. 

The teacher told us, that if we want we can use an ArrayList

This is how I did. 
After some more searches on google.

Answer (score 1):

Try use ready data structure [Blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

If you want implement your own, I recommend look at `java.util.concurrent.locks` package.